# CSV to shapefile in batch ogr2ogr

Tags: ogr2ogr

I have a folder called `CSV`, in it there are several CSV files with coordinates and attributes.

1. I want to convert all files in a CSV folder into shapefiles
2. New created shapefiles should have original CSV file name
3. All newly created shapefiles should be placed in another folder called `SHP`.
4. Once all shapefiles created, merge all shapefiles into one (could go over a GB)

For this, I tried to play around with ogr2ogr, had a bit of success but could’t go further.

For example, one web page shows to create (1) Create a dbf file (2) Create a vrt file (3) Create the shapefile by using ogr2ogr.

I can recreate what it says but I can’t workout how to point a folder i.e. CSV and convert all files in that into shapefiles.

Once I could accomplish above then, I would like a simple ogr2oge like command to merge all shapefiles into one shapefile.

Another point: Is there any way to use just text.bat file for above processes instead of OSGeo4W shell?

Comment: Please ask only one question per Question, as emphasized by the [Tour]. Coding questions should include the code in the body of the question, along with a complete description of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I use script from [here](https://gist.github.com/dimejimudele/ddb7f16578acfaa4348ebe39145a186d) to batch convert from csv to shp. It required python 3x and the library like pandas geopandas fiona and shapely.